# modifying another spreadsheet from within a spreadsheet : Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to modify data in a spreadsheet based on the data entered in another spreadsheet. To access the data within the sheet i can use the SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); function but how to reference another spreadsheet from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reference another spreadsheet you need to find its Id

Look at the URL

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/THIS IS THE ID/edit#gid=0

copy the Id from the URL

In the sheet that you want to read this from create a reference by using this

var othersheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("PUT THE ID IN HERE");

Now when you use othersheet you can access anything onit., assuming you have permission

Comment: Glad you were able to integrate that.  A up-vote or right answer would be appreciated, I need the reputation boost!

Comment: i can give u a right answer, still not enough reputation with me for an upvote though

Answer (score 0):

You could also build a `doPost()` function in the sheet #2, deploy as API.
This allows you to trigger actions in that sheet by HTTP request.

Depending on the size of the code, this can be easier to manage since every sheet is only manipulating itself.